# Adding Refernce to a Javascript file in a plain .js file

Tags: javascript, signalr

I want to create a SignalR client in JavaScript. Am not using any HTML files(its not a web application).My intention is to create ".js" file and connect to the SignalR hub and subscribe to the events,and when the events got triggered I want to output the data to a console.
So how can I refer "signalR-2.1.0.min.js" in my plain .js file.

```
<script src="Scripts/signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

The above way of reference works only with HTML files.This is working fine in my web application.
But if I want to run a ".js" file for the same purpose (as a SignalR client without html files)how can I add reference to this "signalR-2.1.0.min.js" file?

Thanks In Advance
Susmitha

Comment: How do you run the JS file? Do you use node.js?

Comment: No am  not using Node.js.                                                                                    Am using Cscript.exe to run the JS file

Answer (score 0):

If you your using Node.js, you can just use require:

```
const myFile = require('./myScript.js');
```

Comment: I am not using Node.js.

Comment: oh, I don't think it is possible to include stuff client-side :/
You could use something like Browserify or require.js though?

Comment: Hi  DoeDoeDoe  ,Ok.I will try.